# How to facet data using 3 conditions using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a big data frame (more than 400,000 rows) named as `df`.

## About Dataset

This data set is related to vehicle movements in every 0.1 seconds. The relevant variables for this question are explained below:
`class` & `pclass` = Class of vehicle i.e. 1=motorcycle, 2=car, 3=truck
`id` = Unique ID of a vehicle
`frame` = Unique ID of a frame in which vehicle was observed. Every frame is 0.1 seconds long
`svel` = Velocity of a subject vehicle
`pvel` = Velocity of a vehicle which is in front of  (preceding) subject vehicle

## Question

I want to do following with the data set:

1. Subset the data set based on the `class` & `pclass`.
   This will create 4 cases: car following car, car following truck,
   truck following car and truck following truck
2. Create plots for each id in each of the above 4 cases which should be between `frame` and Velocity (both `svel` and `pvel` i.e. 2
   lines on a single plot)

## What I've tried

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),each=5),
                 frame=rep(1:5,5),
                 class=rep(c(2,3,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,2), each=5),
                 svel=c(15,20,30,15,25,69,45,25,36,45,25,45,45,45,44,40,38,39,39,40,33,34,35,26,50,50,50,50,45,44,43,46,40,35,34,33,32,31,30,32,34,36,38,42,44,46,48,50,52,56),
                 pclass=rep(c(0,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,2,2), each=5),
              pvel=c(0,0,0,0,0,15,20,30,15,25,69,45,25,36,45,25,45,45,45,44,40,38,39,39,40, 33,34,35,26,50,50,50,50,45,44,43,46,40,35,34,33,32,31,30,32,34,36,38,42,44))
```

I wrote 2 pieces of code to create plots as follows:

```
  ggplot(data=df, aes(group=id)) + 
      geom_line(mapping=aes(x=frame, y=svel, linetype='subject vehicle')) +
      geom_line(mapping=aes(x=frame, y=pvel, linetype='preceding vehicle')) +
      scale_linetype(name = "Vehicle") +
      facet_grid(class~pclass)
```

[image]

and:

```
  ggplot(data=df, aes(color=as.factor(id))) + 
      geom_line(mapping=aes(x=frame, y=svel)) +
      geom_point(mapping=aes(x=frame, y=pvel)) +
      scale_linetype(name = "Vehicle") +
      facet_grid(class~pclass)
```

[image]

They somewhat solve the problem of faceting but I want to create a separate plot for every vehicle ID. You can see that right now each plot contains more than 1 id. How can I do that?

Comment: Facets are based on Tufte's idea of "small multiples", and are useful when all the plots off the same data frame, with a data column(s) specifying which data goes in each facet. If your plots are different, then you're better off using `grid.arrange` or one of the other tools mentioned [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22996454/903061).

Comment: Also, since you have two problems that aren't interrelated, asking two different questions probably makes sense. If you want help figuring out how to format your data so facets work, that's a worthwhile question. If you just want to know how to stick plots together, it will probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @shujaa faceting is important but since data is same I think it would be easy to reply to both in one answer

Comment: I ran your code. I don't see the grid line issue. Is it illustrated in this data? I'd encourage you to continue trying with the intended gridline functions (panel.grid.major et al.)--make sure you call them *after* you add a theme otherwise they will be overwritten. Also, the data you shared only has one `VehicleID` so it doesn't illustrate your faceting problem either. However that can probably be solved by not using a for loop and instead using `+ facet_wrap(~ Vehicle.ID)`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will investigate more on gridlines. I've provided some sample data and shown some progress, please see how it can be improved

Comment: Your question is gigantic. It has many small parts that are unrelated. Once again, I suggest you try to break your problem into small pieces, work on them one at a time, and post a small question showing exactly where you're stuck on each piece. Right now 3/4 of your question is unrelated to the title, and it would take someone a long time to answer completely. If you ask small questions, it lets one person answer one piece at a time. In that way, small questions are easier to answer and provide a better resource for future users looking for help.

Comment: Extra details are removed now. Only asking about faceting now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want a list of plots. I like to use `plyr::dlply` for this. Wrap the code to create a plot in a function, call it something like `makePlot`. (Don't worry about `group = id` in your function, `plyr` will only pass data with 1 `id` at a time.)

Then you can do this:

```
library(plyr)
myplots <- dlply(.data = df, .variables = id, .fun = makePlot)
```

Then, `myplots` should be a `list` of `ggplots`. You can print them one at a time with `print(myplots[[1]])`, you can continue to modify them, and if you want to arrange them all, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6681145/903061) should at least get you a very good start.

If, on the other hand, you like the faceting approach and would like to use it for `id`, you can give `facet_grid` a bigger formula, like `facet_grid(class ~ id + pclass)`, but this could make for a very big plot if you have a lot of `id`s.

#### Edits:

I don't know offhand what's wrong with `dlply` and your `makePlot`. You can always do a loop instead:

```
myplots <- list()
for (i in unique(df$id)) {
    myplots[[i]] <- makePlot(filter(df, id == i))
}
```

Looking more carefully at your function and data, you could restructure things like this:

```
library(reshape2)
dfm <- melt(df, id.vars = c("id", "frame", "class", "pclass"),
            variable.name = "Vehicle", value.name = "Velocity")
levels(dfm$Vehicle) <- c("Subject Vehicle", "Preceding Vehicle")
```

Then a plot for an individual id gets as simple as

```
ggplot(data=subset(dfm, id == 1), aes(x = frame, y = Velocity)) +
       geom_line(mapping=aes(linetype = Vehicle))
```

Comment: I can't seem to create a plotting function. I tried this: `makePlot <- function(x){
  ggplot(data=x) + 
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=frame, y=svel, linetype='subject vehicle')) +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=frame, y=pvel, linetype='preceding vehicle')) +
  scale_linetype(name = "Vehicle") +
  facet_grid(class~pclass)}`