# Multiple plots lay out as upper triangle matrix and formatted as scatter plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am doing a Bayesian modeling and I have 8 variables, for each variable there is a correlation parameter, and each pair of variables have a correlation parameter. All those parameters have their posterior density plot. I would like to arrange those plots in a upper triangle layout, and I used the result from 
[Upper triangle layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996454/arrange-n-ggplots-into-lower-triangle-matrix-shape)

However, it would be better if I can title/label the plots in the same fashion as what scatter plot does, i.e., I will only have titles(variable names) in the top and in the right, and by checking the corresponding titles on the top and right of each sub figure, people will know what the correlation parameter is standing for.

Here is minimum example I have achieved, where I only used 3 variables for illustration.

```
require(ggplot2)
corr_1 = rnorm(100)
corr_2 = rnorm(100)
corr_12 = rnorm(100)
corr_list = list(corr_1, corr_2, corr_12)
ttls = c('variance within variable 1',
         'correlation within variable 1 & 2',
         'variance within variable 2')
plots = list()
for(i in 1:3){
  temp_df = data.frame(x=corr_list[[i]])
  temp = ggplot(data=temp_df, aes(x=x)) +
    geom_density()+
    ggtitle(ttls[i])
  plots[[i]] = temp
}
library(gridExtra) ## for grid.arrange()
library(grid)
ng <- nullGrob()
grid.arrange(plots[[1]], plots[[2]],         
             ng, plots[[3]])
```

[image]

So what I want is instead of explicitly stating what the correlation means, having labels in the top of the plot. I should have title "variable1" and "variable2" on top, and on the right of the plot,  I have title "variable1" and "variable2" vertically, just like what the scatter plots does.

The final layout I'd like to have is similar to this one:
[image]

However, the difference is that mine plots requires the off diagonal parts to be all density plot, and all the density plots are independent, i.e., the data does not depend on other variables, as in my minimum example, I have independent plots stored in a list( while in a pairwise scatter plot, each subplot is using one variable as x, one as y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have your plots appropriately arranged, and that all you need is to add the variable labels. I've made a couple of changes to the plot function to remove titles and axis labels.

`arrangeGrob` returns a grob which is also a gtable. Thus, `gtable` functions can be applied to add the labels. I've added some comments below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

corr_1 = rnorm(100)
corr_2 = rnorm(100)
corr_12 = rnorm(100)
corr_list = list(corr_1, corr_2, corr_12)
ttls = c('variance within variable 1',
         'correlation within variable 1 & 2',
         'variance within variable 2')
plots = list()
for(i in 1:3){
  temp_df = data.frame(x=corr_list[[i]])
  temp = ggplot(data=temp_df, aes(x=x)) +
    geom_density() +

    theme(axis.title = element_blank()) #+

  #  ggtitle(ttls[i])
  plots[[i]] = temp
}

ng <- nullGrob()
gp <- arrangeGrob(plots[[1]], plots[[2]],         
             ng, plots[[3]])

# The gp object is a gtable;
# thus gtable functions can be applied to add the the necessary labels

# A list of text grobs - the labels
vars <- list(textGrob("Variable 1"), textGrob("Variable 2"))

# So that there is space for the labels,
# add a row to the top of the gtable,
# and a column to the left of the gtable.
gp <- gtable_add_cols(gp, unit(1.5, "lines"), 0)
gp <- gtable_add_rows(gp, unit(1.5, "lines"), 0)

# Add the label grobs.
# The labels on the left should be rotated; hence the edit.
# t and l refer to cells in the gtable layout.
# gtable_show_layout(gp) shows the layout.
gp <- gtable_add_grob(gp, lapply(vars, editGrob, rot = 90), t = 2:3, l = 1)
gp <- gtable_add_grob(gp, vars, t = 1, l = 2:3)

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gp)
```

[image]