# Save multiple ggplots from a for loop in a single plot in a particular layout

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to plot a single image that contains 35 ggplots. The order of the plots in the single image is fixed and is shown below.

[image]

I also want blank grids as shown in the grid image. Each grid should have the plot with a particular drug number. I have a data frame "drug_dctv2" which I am splitting, and making into a list to read data into the for loop.

The problem is: In plot_list[[i]], only the last plot is saved 35 times with i (1 to 35). I am also not sure how to save the plots in the particular order as shown in the grid.

Through my internet search, I found library like "[cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html)" and "[gridextra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html)" but I couldn't find a proper way to implement these.
I made a plot layout file which contains the drug names in the following order as shown in the grid image and in place of blank spaces, I inserted "tab". But I do not find a way to proceed from there.
I am new to R. Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.

Data set looks like as shown below. Each Drug has 10 data points.

```
**Drug_name    conc    viab**
Drug_1       1         1.0265
Drug_1       0.1       1.2365
Drug_1       0.01      0.5896
--          --        --
Drug_2       1         2.0584
Drug_2       0.1       1.0277
Drug_2       0.01      1.5696
--          --        --
```

#

```
split <- split(file,rep(1:35,each=10)) #### this will be used in the for loop

    plot_list = list()
    for(i in 1:length(split))
    {
      data <- split[[i]]
      c <- data$conc
      v <- data$viab

    p = ggplot(data = data,aes(x=c,y=v))+geom_point()+ylim(0,1.5)+
        scale_x_continuous(trans='log10')+
          theme(axis.text = element_blank(),axis.title = element_blank()) +
          geom_line(data=line_data, aes(x=x,y=y2),color ="red",size=1)

      plot_list[[i]] = p
    }
```

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: `aes()` works best with column names, not vectors. Try changing to `aes(x = conc, y = viab)`

Comment: have a look if facet_grid can resolve your issue,

Comment: It worked. Now the plot_list[i] has all the plots. I also found another way to do it. I used aes_string() instead of aes() and that works with vector also. Any suggestions to make the grid single image ? Thank you @GregorThomas

Comment: Maybe look into [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22996454/903061) for that. If you have trouble, make a small reproducible example (like, maybe 3 plots with 1 or 2 points on them each, and one blank plot), share the sample data, show what you tried, and we can help get you there.

Comment: As for the order, you need to define it somewhere. As a start, I would suggest adding `names()` to your `plot_list`, and getting a vector of the order you want them plotted in. But whether that vector should be column-major or row-major order, and how the blanks should be included, will depend on the plot combining solution.

Answer (score 1):

ggplot, as many tidyverse packages, use delayed non standard evaluation. The expression you provide inside aes is not evaluated until the plot is built (e.g. printed or saved).

The expression in your question refers to the vectors `c` and `v` defined in the for loop. These vectors change on each iteration, but the aes call only contains an expression to the reference to `c` and `v` in the environment where the for loop is running, so the `c` and `v` values used in the plot are the ones available when the plot is printed or saved.

You can, as mentioned in the comments, use a column from the data frame directly, since ggplot evaluates the data frame when ggplot() is called.

An alternative if you wanted to keep using `c` and `v`, is to make sure each iteration runs in an independent environment, so ggplot references for `c` and `v` point to the different `c` and `v` on each loop iteration. This can be done for instance replacing the for loop with an `lapply` call.

```r
plot_list <- lapply(split, function(data_drug) {
      c <- data_drug$conc
      v <- data_drug$viab
      ggplot(data = data_drug,aes(x=c,y=v))+geom_point()+ylim(0,1.5)+
        scale_x_continuous(trans='log10')+
          theme(axis.text = element_blank(),axis.title = element_blank()) +
          geom_line(data=line_data, aes(x=x,y=y2),color ="red",size=1)
    })
```

This is one beautiful example where a for loop and an lapply call produce different results and it's a great learning experience about non standard evaluation and variable environments.

To combine the plots look at `cowplot::plot_grid` https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html

Something like this should work

```r
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(
  plot_list[[35]], plot_list[[5]], plot_list[[3]], plot_list[[2]],
  plot_list[[34]], plot_list[[1]], plot_list[[4]], plot_list[[6]],
  plot_list[[32]], plot_list[[8]], NULL, NULL,
  plot_list[[30]], plot_list[[7]], plot_list[[33]] , NULL,
  labels = "AUTO", ncol = 4
)
```

You can put all the function arguments in a list and use do.call to call the function with the arguments:

```r
plot_order <- c(
  35, 5, 3, 2,
  34, 1, 4, 6,
  32, 8, NA, NA
)

plot_grid_args <- c(plot_list[plot_order], list(ncol = 4))
do.call(plot_grid, plot_grid_args)
```

Comment: To combine the plots, I have tried out this method of using plot_grid() but this in is not an efficient way of doing it. In case I have more than 100 plots then what would I do. @zeehio

Comment: As an alternative to cowplot, see the comments on your question. They link to relevant stackoverflow questions regarding plot order using grid.arrange.

Answer (score 0):

So, Finally I was able to solve this problem.

I made a variable layout with the position of the drugs as they are in the split[i] list. For eg: **drug_35 has to come first on the grid and it is on 35th position in split[i] list, so in "layout" variable 35 comes first and so on.**

I made a **text file with the grid layout** as shown above in the image and then read that file in the R script and by some lines of codes I was able to make the layout variable. For the sake of simplicity I am not showing those code lines here. But, I hope the concept is clear.

```
lay <- read.delim("layout.txt",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,sep = "\t", header = F)

lay1 = c(t(lay))

col_n = ncol(lay)
row_n = nrow(lay)

split <- split(file,rep(1:35,each=10))

## layout = 35 5 3 2 34 1 4 6 32 8 0 0 30 7 33 .....
## 0 means blank spaces

png("PLOT.png", width = 6, height = 10, units = "in", res = 400)
par(mfrow=c(row_n,col_n),mar=c(2,0.7,1.5,0.5))  ## margins: bottom, left, top and right

for(i in layout)
{
   if(i== 0) { frame(); next; }
   ## Here if 0 comes then the for loop will be skipped and frame() will generate a blank in the grid image

data <- split[[i]]
      c <- data$conc
      v <- data$viab

plot(c,v,xlab = NULL,ylab = NULL, axes = F,log = "x")
}
dev.off()
```